# Smartech pushToken/oldPushToken is blank

Tags: android, notifications, sdk, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

We are using the Smartech SDK 3.0.1, I have integrated the SDK method to set FCM token but when I see the SDK logs I get pushToken and oldPushToken values as blank. In my **logs** I can see my token is present. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
{
  "advertiserId": "",
  "eventId": "99",
  "pushTokens": [
    {
      "gwSource": 1,
      "pushToken": "",
      "pushTokenOld": ""
    }
  ],
  "guid": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "carrier": "",
  "deviceHeight": "1280",
  "appId": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "deviceLocale": "en",
  "radio": "UNKNOWN",
  "deviceWidth": "800",
  "deviceMake": "lenovo",
  "vendorId": "",
  "countryCode": "",
  "appVersion": "1.0",
  "sdkVersion": "3.0.1",
  "appBuild": "1",
  "useAdvId": false,
  "osName": "android",
  "pushTokenOld": "",
  "eventTime": "1604323968134",
  "osVersion": "7.1.1",
  "deviceModel": "lenovo tb-x304l",
  "appBundleId": "com.mysampleapp",
  "pushToken": "",
  "eventName": "device_common_data",
  "bod": 3602
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed capturing the token and passing to SDK. Use the below workaround in your application class. This snippet will fetch the generated FCM token from Firebase and set it to SDK.

```
private void setFCMPushToken(final Context context) {
        try {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        Smartech smartech = Smartech.getInstance(new WeakReference<>(context));
                        String fcmToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        String currentToken = smartech.getDevicePushToken();

                        Log.i("TOKEN", "FCM Instance Id Token: " + fcmToken);
                        Log.i("TOKEN", "Current FCM Token: " + currentToken);

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(currentToken)) {
                            smartech.setDevicePushToken(fcmToken);
                            Log.i("TOKEN", "New token set: " + fcmToken);
                        } else if (!currentToken.equals(fcmToken)) {
                            smartech.setDevicePushToken(fcmToken);
                            Log.i("TOKEN", "New token set: " + fcmToken);
                        } else {
                            Log.i("TOKEN", "Both tokens are same.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TOKEN", "Failed to set token.");
        }
    }
```